# Play 2 - Scala - Forms Validators and radio buttons

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm need render a Form with validators for this model:

Model:

```
    case class Service (
        name: String, description: String, unitcost: Long,
            typo: Char, isactive: Char, modifiedby: String)
```

Controller:

```
    import play.api.data.Form
    import play.api.data._
    import play.api.data.format.Formats._
    import play.api.data.Forms._

    object Services extends Controller {
....
....
    private val servicesForm[Service] = Form(
    mapping(
        "name" -> nonEmptyText.verifying(
            "validation.name.duplicate", Service.findByName(_).isEmpty),
        "description" -> nonEmptyText,
        "unitcost" -> longNumber,
        "typo" -> of[Char],
        "isactive" -> of[Char],
        "modifiedby" -> nonEmptyText
        ) (Service.apply)(Service.unapply)
    )
```

This code fails on every *of[Char]* saying that its needed import play.api.data.format.Formats._ 
but I was..
My second doubt is about how to put a radio button pair for each (typo and isactive)
thinking that typo has "M" and "A" like options and isactive has "Y" and "N".

PD: I think put this using a persistence model after...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the Form does not know how to handle the `Char` type. There is no default defined for the `Char` type.

To solve the problem you have two options:

1. Change the type from `Char` to `String` for which a default `Formatter` exists
2. Supply a `Formatter` for `Char`

A formatter would look something like this (note that it does not have the correct error handling)

```
implicit val charFormat = new Formatter[Char] {
  def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]):Either[Seq[FormError], Char] = 
    data.get(key)
    .filter(_.length == 1)
    .map(_.head)
    .toRight(Seq(FormError(key, "error.required", Nil)))

  def unbind(key: String, value: Char) = Map(key -> value.toString)
}
```