# Play Framework 2.1 / form mapping with complex objects

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.1

Play Framework documentation for Scala shows a sample mapping a form to a case class implicitly:

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int)

val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "age" -> number
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
```

We notice that only primitive values are used in this unique sample.

How about if we make this alteration:

```
case class Car(brandName: String)

case class User(name: String, car: Car)
```

Moreover, let's assume that the form returns the `User`'s name (String) and a `carId`(String)

```
val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "car" -> carRepository.findById(nonEmptyText)  // concept I wish
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
```

Is there any way to instantiate a car at this wished line with some `carId` provided for example by the form and ensuring also that the `carId` is not an empty `String`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For first part of your question, documentation also shows Nested values:

```
case class Car(brandName: String)
case class User(name: String, car: Car)

val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "car" -> mapping(
        "brandName" -> text
    )(Car.apply)(Car.unapply)
  )(User.apply, User.unapply)
)
```

Comment: Or two..."More Caffeine!" ;) . YW. Although EECOLOR's answer below may solve both problems.I am looking into Formatter now.

Comment: :) Actually, your solution could solve both problems by using a `verifying` method on the nested mapping returning a `Constraint` and an associated error message. The `verifying`'s argument method will thus validate through database the `Car`.

Comment: true. verifying will suffice for validation. I assumed you need binding instead with that particular syntax.

Comment: One thing that your solution may not do: Inserting the primitive `Car` data into an intermediary object `PossibleCar` in order to proceed to validation before returning a valid `Car` (think to builder pattern); `Car`'s `apply` method being inaccessible from outside world (private) and only accessible from its associated `PossibleCar`. With @EECOLOR formatter solution, it sounds like an easy game to performs this procedure ;)

Comment: verifying takes Constraint definitions, which you can use to validate the Car data in any way you wish, including checking if it exists in carRepository. Please see following blog post which explains process  in detail: http://mikeslinn.blogspot.in/2013/02/domain-entity-level-validation-for-play.html

Comment: I agree but nested mapping syntax involves the use of apply method from case class. But this one isn t accessible from outside for safety(complex  builder pattern instead)

Answer (score 5):

You could supply a `Formatter` and use the `of[Car]` method.

```
implicit val carFormat = new Formatter[Car] {
  def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]):Either[Seq[FormError], Car] = 
    data.get(key)
      // make sure the method returns an option of Car
      .flatMap(carRepository.findByBrandName _)
      .toRight(Seq(FormError(key, "error.carNotFound", Nil)))

  def unbind(key: String, value: Car) = Map(key -> value.brandName)
}
```

This answer provides another `Formatter`: [Play 2 - Scala - Forms Validators and radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054920/play-2-scala-forms-validators-and-radio-buttons/15045212#15045212)

You can then use it like this:

```
val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "car" -> of[Car]
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Late coming to this, but I just released a utility to help with this! Using your classes, your code would look like this:

```scala
case class Car(brandName: String)
object Car { implicit val mapping = CaseClassMapping.mapping[Car] }

case class User(name: String, car: Car)
object User { implicit val mapping = CaseClassMapping.mapping[User] }

val userForm = Form(implicitly[Mapping[User]])
```

You can find the source and instructions for including it in your project on github: https://github.com/Iterable/iterable-play-utils